# Splitting string by comma or colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split string by comma or colon.

```
a-bc-de:fghij,klmn:opqrs should return an array of a-bc-de,fghij,klmn,opqrs
```

I've tried `split(":|,") abd ("[^a-z]+")` but I don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are splitting by a string. If you want to split using a regex, you have to use the right syntax :

```
split(/:|,/)
```

Documentation link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: You even don't need pipe: `[:,]`

Comment: That is true, but I just wanted to correct the error OP made. The rest is up to them

Comment: @CircleofLife don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check icon under the score so people will see the question as answered :)

Comment: MDN says that regex splitting is not in all browsers.

Comment: @forthe This information has a very high chance of beeing outdated. The author of this info in the docs wrote it in 2008, with no other information to support it. I think we can safely assume it is working across all browsers today.

Note : I edited the doc to remove this information (a decade old !) and asked for a technical review so other people could check it too.